# Angular, Generate Tag with ngFor loop and get it with ViewChild

Tags: angular, tags, ngfor, viewchild

I have a problem... Actually I'm working on a grid I generated it, this part works.
But now I need to retrieve the position and I would like to use viewChild with a tag Like below :

**Map.html:**
[image: Map.html]

**Map.ts:**
[image: Map.ts]

I know that ideally I should create my 'viewChild someInput' in the callback line 41.But when I tried and It just told that 'declaration expected' and as it really new for me this technology I have no idea how to do :/

So to recap, how use these tag after that my script generated my grid ??  plz

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) to perform some actions after the dom is loaded.

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // do things
    }
    ...
}
```

To get the position of the div, I suggest using vanilla JavaScript : 
in .html :

```
<div class={{getData(x, y)}} id={{x}}{{y}}> {{x}}{{y}} </div>
```

in .ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     let element = document.getElementById(yourPosition);
}
```

Remark : if you want to get all your "seat" elements, you can use [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: And if i get my element by class I'll retrive the id right? If yes ill make with class
But I tried with getElementById it seems to be an interesting way but I still cant get my element it told me that its 'null' when i tried to display it

Comment: If you get your elements by class, you will be able to retrieve the id of each element, but I think this is trickier than directly getting elements by id. Have you used the AfterViewInit method?

Comment: Yes but its still a null response and it display before my map generated :/